# Express won't serve acme-challenge static file without extension

Tags: node.js, express, lets-encrypt

I struggle to validate the Let's Encrypt challenge on my server. I have properly set up my server and it serves files as expected, except when they don't have extensions (which is the case for the SSL challenges).

`app.use("/.well-known", express.static(path.join(__dirname, ".well-known"), { dotfiles: "allow" }) );`

For instance:

- `.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt` works as expected
- `.well-known/acme-challenge/test` won't work (resource not found)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure out the answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I went for a reverse-proxy (traefik) that handles the SSL verification for all of my containers and their respective subdomains. My express server now only listens for http requests. Works nicely once the setup is done.

Comment: I figured this out and will post a long answer to this shortly.  My solution uses docker but it should work for your case also.

Comment: Sorry took forever to post my answer, but let me know what you think @jodoox

Comment: Note that my solution allows you to still have https :).

Comment: Thanks for your input. As long as you are using docker, I feel like using a reverse proxy like `traefik` is easier, as it will essentially handle all the cert verification / renewal part in a few lines of code. This also makes the express server leaner as it listens on http only (external requests are forwarded by traefik), and you can easily extend your reverse-proxy should you want to run additional services.

Comment: I would be interested to see how you set that up if you can make an answer later! Very curious how that all works.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I think the best would be here to follow a tutorial (my config is fairly custom). This one https://dev.to/paularah/deploy-and-automatically-provision-ssl-certs-on-a-node-js-server-with-traefik-and-docker-2j0e seems to be pretty short. 

Any reverse-proxy (nginx caddy ...) would work, I picked Traefik because it's free, OSS, has good performance, and I found the docker container auto-discovery ability to be pretty useful (once the proxy is set up you'll only have to add a few labels to your `docker-compose.yml` to make any new service available with SSL)

Answer (score 0):

I want to document my solution to this issue using docker to automate the process of using certbot to get/set certificates.  If you are not using docker just skip to server.js, but make sure you understand the shell script and how it calls the certonly command.

First I recommend you set up your docker compose file like the following:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  main_website:
    image: yourimage:latest
    build: 
      context: ./
      target: dev
    ports:
      - "443:443" #- Expose SSL Port for HTTPS
      - "80:8080" # - Public Main Website Vue
      - "8000:8000" # - Vue Dev
      - "8001:8001" #- Vue UI
    volumes:
      - "./web:/usr/src/app"
      - "./server:/usr/src/server"
      - "./server/crontab:/etc/crontabs/root"
      - "./certbot:/var/www/certbot/:ro"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"] #-c stands for running sh in string mode so I can run npm install and run start:dev at the same time
    command: #-Note that when vue (from npm run serve runs its package json has an & at the end which makes it run in the background allowing the other server to also run)
      - "npm install && npm run build && npm run serve && npm run ui && cd /usr/src/server && npm install && npm run start:dev"
    env_file:
     - db_dev.env
     - stripe_dev.env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: "dev"
    depends_on:
      - db_dev
      - db_live
      - stripe
      - cerbot
    container_name: website_and_api_trading_tools_software
    healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail http://localhost:8080/ || exit 1"
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
  db_dev:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --group_concat_max_len=1844674407370954752
    volumes:
      - ./db_dev_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    container_name: db_dev_trading_tools_software
    env_file:
     - db_dev.env
  db_live:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --group_concat_max_len=1844674407370954752
    volumes:
      - ./db_live_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    container_name: db_live_trading_tools_software
    env_file:
     - db_live.env
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db_live
      - db_dev
    container_name: phpmyadmin_trading_tools_software
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 25000000
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  stripe:
    container_name: stripe_trading_tools_software
    image: stripe/stripe-cli:latest
    restart: always
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    env_file:
     - stripe_dev.env
    command: 
      - "stripe listen --api-key ${STRIPE_TEST_API_KEY} --forward-to main_website:8080/webhook --format JSON"
  certbot:
    container_name: certbot_tradingtools_software
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - "./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw"
      - "./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw"
```

Things to note for this file are that I created a volume on the main_website container.  This will have access to the files that the webroot check from the certbot will need and will also store the certificates later in the 'conf' directly that will be here.

```
- "./certbot:/var/www/certbot/:ro"
```

Volumes of note for the certbot container are listed below.  The `/var/www/certbot` path is where the webroot files will go which will create the files `.well-known/acme-challenge/randomfilejiberishhere`, and the `/etc/letsencrypt` path is where the actual certificates are placed.

```
volumes:
      - "./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw"
      - "./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw"
```

Note that I add :rw at the end of the volume path to enable read/write and I put :ro to enable read only for the main_website container as a good practice to follow.  This step is optional.

The next thing to note, is you will want a healthcheck on your main_website to be sure it's up and running before we start creating webroot checks with certbot against it.

```
healthcheck:
      test: "curl --fail http://localhost:8080/ || exit 1"
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
```

This will every 20 seconds attempt to curl into the website from within the container until it gets a valid response.  When you docker compose up, just add the --wait flag, like this: `docker compose up --wait` (this will wait for the health check to finish before moving onto the next step)

Note that with this setup the **certbot container and main_website essentially have access to the same volume.**

Next, I recommend creating a shell script like the following.

**certbot.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#@JA - To use this file pass as an argument the domain name of interest attempting to renew or create.
#https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell (refer to string comparison technique for dates)
date +"%Y%m%d" > ./certbot/last-cert-run.txt
docker compose run --rm certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot/ -d $1 -d $2 --non-interactive --agree-tos -m youremailhere@gmail.com --dry-run -v --expand
if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
then
    echo "Dry run succesful, attempting to create real certificate and/or automatically renew by doing so..."

    #@JA - The rate limit is 5 certificates created per week.  For this reason, this command should only run if it has been one week since the last run.
    #@JA - Read (if it exists) the date from the last-successful-cert-run.txt file.  If it has been at least a week since then, then we are allowed to run.

    #@JA - The date command is different on Linux vs Mac, so we need to identify the system before using it.
    unameOut="$(uname -s)"
    case "${unameOut}" in
        Linux*)     machine=Linux;;
        Darwin*)    machine=Mac;;
        CYGWIN*)    machine=Cygwin;;
        MINGW*)     machine=MinGw;;
        *)          machine="UNKNOWN:${unameOut}"
    esac
    echo "machine=$machine"

    current_date=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
    last_date=$(cat ./certbot/last-successful-cert-run.txt)
    
    if [ "$machine" = "Darwin" ];then
        one_week_from_last_date=$(date -jf "%Y%m%d" -v +7d "$last_date" +"%Y%m%d")
    else
        one_week_from_last_date=$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "$last_date +7 days")
    fi

    echo "last_date=$last_date"
    echo "current_date=$current_date"
    echo "one_week_from_last_date=$one_week_from_last_date"

    #@JA - This will renew every 7 days, well within the rate limit.
    if [ $current_date -ge $one_week_from_last_date ];then
        echo "Time to renew certificate..."
        docker compose run --rm certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot/ -d $1 -d $2 --non-interactive --agree-tos -m youremailhere@gmail.com -v --expand
        date +"%Y%m%d" > ./certbot/last-successful-cert-run.txt
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Not time to renew certificate yet"
        exit 0
    fi    
 else
     echo "Certbot dry run failed."
     exit 1
 fi
```

To use this script you call it like this `certbot.sh domain1.com anotherdomain.com`.  If you want to add more domains just keep adding them but you will have to modify the script to add extra -d commands for each domain in the --dry-run version of the certbot command and the non --dry-run version.

**Certbot only allows 5 failed validation attempts before you are blocked for an hour**

For this reason you should ALWAYS attempt a --dry-run test first to be sure everything is setup and ONLY if that passes attempt a real one.

**Certbot also allows only 5 certificates per week to be issued!**

For this reason, I store the date to a text file when it last ran successfully and only run the actual command to create the certificate if necessary.  Note that I had to add code to calculate the date difference 7 days ahead differently based on if you are running this shell script from a Mac or Linux based system since the date command differs.

Finally, I am **NOT** using certbot renew, because **certonly** essentially does the same thing here.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const logger = require('./logger');//require the logger folder index.js file which will load DEV or PROD versions of logging.
const stripe = require('stripe');
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const certBotPath = '/var/www/certbot/';
const credentialsPath = certBotPath+'conf/live/';
logger.info(`credentialsPath=${credentialsPath}`);

//@JA - Array to hold all the known credentials found.
var credentials_array = [];
try{
    fs.readdirSync(credentialsPath).map( domain_directory => {
        // logger.info("Reading directories for SSL credentials...");
        // logger.info(domain_directory);

        if(domain_directory!="README"){ //@JA - We ignore the README file
            const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
            const certificate = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/cert.pem', 'utf8');
            const ca = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/chain.pem', 'utf8'); 
            
            const credentials = {
                key: privateKey,
                cert: certificate,
                ca: ca,
                domain: domain_directory
            }
            logger.info(`credential object added.. ${domain_directory}`);
            credentials_array.push(credentials);
        }
        
    });
}catch{
    credentials = {};//@JA - Just give a wrong credentials object so it works.
    credentials_array.push(credentials);
}
logger.info("Finished finding credentials...");

const vueBuildPath = '/usr/src/app/build/';//@JA - Path to the vue build files

const app = express();

//@JA - We need a manual check for https because SOME http routes we do NOT want to forward to https, like /.well-known/acme-challenge/:fileid for certbot
var httpsCheck = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.connection.encrypted){
        logger.info(req.url);
        logger.info("SSL Detected, continue to next middleware...!");
        next();//Then continue on as normal.
    }else{
        logger.info("SSL NOT DETECTED!!!")
        logger.info(req.url);
        if(!req.url.includes("/.well-known/acme-challenge/")){
            logger.info("Forcing permanent redirect to port 443 secure...");
            res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
            res.end();
        }else{
            next();//@JA - Let it pass as normal in this case since it's the challenges.
        }
    }
}
app.use(httpsCheck);

app.use(express.static(vueBuildPath));
app.use(express.static(certBotPath));

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// // parse requests of content-type - application/json (@JA - I added the extra ability to get the rawBody so it plays nice with certain webHooks from stripe)
app.use(express.json({
    limit: '5mb',
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    }
}));

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// certbot SSL checking webroot directory
// app.use('/.well-known', express.static(certBotPath));
app.get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:fileid', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(certBotPath+"www/.well-known/acme-challenge/"+req.params.fileid)
})

// Sequelize Database setups
const db = require("./models");
const { info } = require("console");
if(process.env.NODE_ENV=="dev"){
    db.sequelize.sync({force:true})
    .then(() => {
        logger.info("Droped and re-synced db.");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        logger.error("Failed to sync db: " + err.message);
    });
}else{
    db.sequelize.sync({alter:true})
    .then(() => {
        logger.info("Altered & Synced db.");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        logger.error("Failed to sync db: " + err.message);
    });
}

// Routes
// @JA - Main vue application route at /
app.get(["/","/optimizer"], (req, res) => {
  //res.json({ message: "Welcome to tradingtools.software applications." });
  res.sendFile(vueBuildPath + "index.html");
});

// This is your Stripe CLI webhook secret for testing your endpoint locally.
const endpointSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SIGNING_SECRET;
//logger.info(`Stripe endpointSecret=${endpointSecret}`);

//Stripe Webhook
app.post('/webhook', (request, response) => {
    logger.info("Stripe WebHook detected!");

    const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    
    let event;
    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret); //@JA - Had to modify this to take the rawBody since this is what was needed.
    } catch (err) {
        response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        return;
    }

    logger.info(`event_type=${event.type}`);

    // Handle the event
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
            // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
            //logger.info(JSON.stringify(paymentIntent));
            //logger.info("Payment_intent.succeeded!");
        break;
            // ... handle other event types
        default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
    }

    // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
    response.send();
});

require("./routes/user.routes")(app); //@JA - Includes all the API Routes for User

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8080, () =>{
    logger.info(`HTTP Server running on port 8080 via 80 docker-compose, partial redirect active, using app for routes but will forward all 80 port traffic to 443 except for .well-known route`);
});

//@JA - TODO - Make this use first credentials it finds and add anymore as contexts.

logger.info(`using credentials for: ${credentials_array[0].domain} as default`);


const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials_array[0], app);
if(credentials_array.length>1){
    for(let i=0;i<credentials_array.length;i++){
        logger.info(`Adding httpsServer context for ${credentials_array[i].domain}`);
        httpsServer.addContext(credentials_array[i].domain,credentials_array[i]);//@JA - Domain is stored in the credentials object for convinience.
    }
}

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    logger.info(`'HTTPS Server running on port 443!'`);
});
```

Lastly, while most of the code that I pasted is not relevant to this, I will point out the relevant sections to make this work.

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https');
```

You must include these above since you will need to run **BOTH** servers.  The webroot check will NOT work on the SSL version of the directory! For this reason I had to do some workarounds so that the server will never have to shutdown.

```
const certBotPath = '/var/www/certbot/';
const credentialsPath = certBotPath+'conf/live/';
```

These are the paths to the actual certificate and certbot webroot check if you are using the same volume information from docker-compose that I did.

```
var credentials_array = [];
try{
    fs.readdirSync(credentialsPath).map( domain_directory => {
        // logger.info("Reading directories for SSL credentials...");
        // logger.info(domain_directory);

        if(domain_directory!="README"){ //@JA - We ignore the README file
            const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
            const certificate = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/cert.pem', 'utf8');
            const ca = fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath+domain_directory+'/chain.pem', 'utf8'); 
            
            const credentials = {
                key: privateKey,
                cert: certificate,
                ca: ca,
                domain: domain_directory
            }
            logger.info(`credential object added.. ${domain_directory}`);
            credentials_array.push(credentials);
        }
        
    });
}catch{
    credentials = {};//@JA - Just give a wrong credentials object so it works.
    credentials_array.push(credentials);
}
```

This code will attempt to read the credentials path to see if there is any existing certificates created ignoring the README file that will always be present.  If there is any domain certificates found it will add it to the array since you can have multiple certificates added per https server instance by using `.addContext` on the https object as you will see later.

The directory it creates when it successfully creates certificates looks something like this so you understand what my code is doing.  I just blurred out my domain for security reasons.

[image]

```
var httpsCheck = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.connection.encrypted){
        logger.info(req.url);
        logger.info("SSL Detected, continue to next middleware...!");
        next();//Then continue on as normal.
    }else{
        logger.info("SSL NOT DETECTED!!!")
        logger.info(req.url);
        if(!req.url.includes("/.well-known/acme-challenge/")){
            logger.info("Forcing permanent redirect to port 443 secure...");
            res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url });
            res.end();
        }else{
            next();//@JA - Let it pass as normal in this case since it's the challenges.
        }
    }
}
app.use(httpsCheck);
```

The code above is middleware that intercepts every request to the website and if it detects its SSL it lets it continue to the next middleware using the next() command.  If it detects it's NOT encrypted, then it reads the URL and if it sees this is a request for `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` then it will allow it to continue on with the next() command, if it's NOT however, it will redirect the request to the SSL version (https) of that path so that you retain redirection abilities.

```
app.get('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:fileid', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(certBotPath+"www/.well-known/acme-challenge/"+req.params.fileid)
})
```

This code will run whenever the webroot path of /.well-known/acme-challenge if used and I send the file that it's looking for using the known file paths on the main_website docker container instance.  This is essential for it to pass all of it's checks!

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(8080, () =>{
    logger.info(`HTTP Server running on port 8080 via 80 docker-compose, partial redirect active, using app for routes but will forward all 80 port traffic to 443 except for .well-known route`);
});
```

This creates the http server for port 80 access and uses the app so it will still work with the routing we specified earlier.  In my case I'm listening on port 8080 because my docker compose file routes 8080 to 80.

```
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials_array[0], app);
if(credentials_array.length>1){
    for(let i=0;i<credentials_array.length;i++){
        logger.info(`Adding httpsServer context for ${credentials_array[i].domain}`);
        httpsServer.addContext(credentials_array[i].domain,credentials_array[i]);//@JA - Domain is stored in the credentials object for convinience.
    }
}

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    logger.info(`'HTTPS Server running on port 443!'`);
});
```

Finally you create the httpsServer.  I default it with the first credentialObject it can find and then pass it app so it can access all the other routes as normal.  If there is other credentials found it will use the .addContext function to add them as needed.

Then you simply listen on port 443 as usual for an SSL server.

---

In conclusion this is a fully working setup with the official certbot docker file and SSL redirection for all files except what is needed by the webroot check.  The supplied shellscript can easily be run by sending the domain you want and put on a cronjob to periodically check if new certificates are needed and place them in the same directory everytime.

I hope this helps someone else trying to do this as this was a lot of work to figure out.